# Android: Application multiple instances

Tags: android, android-notifications

When I launch my application from launcher following **sequence** takes place:

1. `SplashActivity.java`

   ```
   <activity
     android:name=".splash.SplashActivity"
     android:launchMode="singleTop"
     android:screenOrientation="portrait"
     android:theme="@style/SplashActivityTheme">
   <intent-filter>
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

     <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
   </intent-filter>
   ```
2. `HomeActivity.java`

**Steps to reproduce the Problem:**

3. Application is not running in the background nor is in the pause state.
4. Notification is received and is shown on the status bar.
5. User clicks on the notification and `HomeActivity.java` is launched.

   `FirebaseMessagingService.java`

   ```
   private void sendNotification(String messageBody, String title) {

       Intent intent = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
       intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
       PendingIntent pendingIntent =
           PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

       Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
       NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
           new NotificationCompat.Builder(this).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_ic_notification)
               .setContentTitle(title)
               .setContentText(messageBody)
               .setAutoCancel(true)
               .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
               .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.pantone_375))
               .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

       NotificationManager notificationManager =
           (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
       notificationManager.notify(++count /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
   }
   ```
6. Leave the `HomeActivity.java` open and launch the application from launcher. Another instance of the same application launches and the sequence is `SplashActivity.java` -> `HomeActivity.java`.

**Expected Result**

1. One instance of the application should exists at any given point.
2. If the application is already in open state and user is on `HomeActivity.java` then it should receive the focus.
3. Application is launched by clicking on the notification and application is in an open state. User clicks on the launcher icon, then the old application instance should gain focus.

Answer (score 0):

When ever you are opening `Activity` while `Notification` is clicked just open the following `Activity`. i.e. your `PendingIntent` will open following `Activity`

Please read all the `comments` written in followinng `Activity` so that you will know why this has been created

```
public class NotificationHandlerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //deep linking - resuming app code
        if (isTaskRoot()) {
            // This Activity is the only Activity, so
            //  the app wasn't running. So start the app from the
            //  beginning (redirect to MainActivity)
        } else {
            // App was already running, so just finish, which will drop the user
            //  in to the activity that was at the top of the task stack
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            Uri data = intent.getData();
            //you can put your extra's if any
            finish();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understood, i want to launch obly a single task of each activity. If i'm right in this case you have to use android:launchMode="singleInstance"
In activty AndroidManifest.xml file

Or look at simular flags in this manual

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html

E. G.

> 

```
<activity android:name=". MainActivity" 
> 
>android:launchMode="singleInstance"label="@string/app_name">
```